# tfs exclude directory from 'detected changes'

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Using tfs online I have a mapping to C:\Work

There I have some directories I don't want to be versioning controlled and I keep them out of source control. Problem is VS 2013 show them as detected changes. This are temporary folders (like EmailPickup) that I want to never 'watch' on those folders. Is there any way to do that so Visual Studio stop suggesting me there are detected changes to include ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

found a simple way to doing it.

On the detected changes modal (Promote Candidate Changes is the title) you can right click and ignore by extension and / or folder.

Comment: Ignored folders/path will be stored in a .tfignore file in your workspace root. Check that file into source control if you want others to also have those folders ignored.

Comment: I'd also suggest to edit the file once in a while to add wildcards instead of full path, when possible.